JPARepository Save() throwing errors with Generated Always ID postgres column
I have a table where the PK is set to Generated Always. When running save() on my repository, the server throws
could not execute statement [ERROR: cannot insert a non-DEFAULT value into column "example_id" Detail: Column example_id is an identity column defined as GENERATED ALWAYS Hint: Use OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE to override.
For context, example_id_seq is already created on the db, and example_id is both this table's primary key and a foreign key, and my desired functionality would be to just dis-include the id for insert statements so it can be generated as expected and have it available for PUT, DELETE, GET etc.
Attempt at column definition:
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name= "exampleSeq", sequenceName = "example_id_seq", allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "exampleSeq")
    @Column(name = "example_id")
    private Long exampleId;

I also tried with @Column(name = "example_id", insertable=false) which seemed to be ignored (still threw the insert error on that column)
Am I missing some way to do this within the JPA system, or do i need to completely overwrite save() in order to do what I'm describing?
